# wordpress query, how to query a numeric range

Tags: wordpress, numeric

I currently have a custom field with numeric values in, my goal is to query these numeric values between a range.

What i have is this:

```
'meta_query' => array(
   array(
    'key' => 'score',
    'value' => '1.8', 
    'type' => 'DECIMAL', 
    'compare' => '='     
  )
)
```

This above example doesn't return scores that match 1.8000.. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: "This above example doesn't return scores that match 1.8000". It wouldn't, you are testing for `1.8`, not `1.8000`. Try changing `compare` to `LIKE`, that way it won't look for exact matches.

Comment: @DavidGard That is wrong. Then it won't match exact value. Wordpress offers typecasting. But not for floating values. DECIMAL will cast 1.8 as 2 and NUMERIC will cast 1.8 as 1. Just write "global $wpdb; print_r ($wpdb);" after you do query. You will have query that you can inspect.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `DECIMAL` to `CHAR` and using the between methods for the comparing worked..
The `CHAR` paramater shouldn't have worked but it did..